# SE and SO apps have same icon

Tags: bug, android-app

I was planning to return to the SE app, so I installed it, and when I looked at my home screen, both SE and SO app had the same icon

[image]

So I restarted, but still the same. Thinking that maybe SO had to do something about it, I uninstalled SO and restarted. Voila! Still the same:

[image]

How come SE had the same icon with SO? I was expecting to see the blue message-like logo, but instead it had the SO logo.

Device Info:

- Model/Brand - Cherry Mobile J7
- OS ver - Marshmallow
- Launcher - Nova Launcher *(5.4.1)*
- SE App *(1.0.95)*

Comment: On Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Stack+Exchange

Comment: @Pang Well that's the logo I was expecting to appear after I installed SE app

Comment: It seems more likely that it's a bug in your launcher. The only Stack Overview logo I see in the Stack Exchange package is all white.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd-party home screen? I thought someone screwed up "[round icon](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#circular-icons)" in the manifest file, but when I checked it, there's only a single, standard icon in the manifest, which is the blue SE icon itself. Also, just in case, could you also mention the SE app version? (latest should be 1.0.95)

Comment: @andrewt I am using another launcher. and the SE version is 1.0.95 too

Comment: Could you also mention the launcher in the question? Now I suspect the launcher has its own icon packs that override the default icon...

Comment: I think you meant to write "voilà" (or "voila"). "[Viola](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viola#French)" is a different word.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is not Stack Exchange's fault, but **an icon pack for Nova Launcher** is the culprit.

Nova Launcher's default (system) icon pack doesn't have this problem:

[image: default system icon pack]

However, custom icon packs such as [Pixel Icon Pack 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.themezilla.pixelui) overrides the default app's icon:

[image: "Pixel" icon]

So, please <s>nag the author</s> give feedback to the icon pack creator to let this fixed.